# Are there functions without .call() and .apply() methods?

Tags: javascript

In “You Don’t Know JS”, the author says at some point:

> «Technically, JavaScript host environments sometimes provide functions which are special enough that they do not have [`call(..)` and `apply(..)` methods]. But those are few»

I really don’t remember seeing / using a function that wouldn’t have these methods. What could be the examples of those?

Comment: The author is talking about environments

Comment: @evolutionxbox What’s that?

Comment: Environments include, the browser, nodejs, etc

Comment: These don’t look like “special functions” though. I think, the author meant something different

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there can be:

```
 function test() { }
 Object.setPrototypeOf(test, {});

 test();
 test.call(); // doesnt work
```

I've never seen such a thing anywhere though.